# Boolean not working - Cutting Hole doesnt completely Cut

Tags: modifiers, faces

i am trying to design a room. Therefore i need to cut some holes (as Windows) into a face of the Room. Doing this with the first Window worked easily, but the second is not working properly as seen in this clip: https://streamable.com/ttt2a9
Anyone has an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
SorPlex

Answer (score 2):

Blender's Boolean system expects to cut "solid" objects. Your roof is not solid. Blender does what you expect on the first side, but is confused when it comes to the second side because there is another face causing Blender to treat that part as "Solid" so you get an indentation instead of a hole.

The easiest fix is to add a Solidify modifier to the roof object above the Boolean modifier.

Another fix would be to separate the end wall face into its own object temporarily.

Comment: Thanks, using the Solidify modifier fixed it :D

Comment: Even works on top of (actually below the stack) mirror modifier, never thought that would be needed. but It saved my day, Thanks.